# CALCULAR PORCENTAGEM DE VENDEDORES

Tags: python

A QUESTAO QUE PEDE O SEGUINTE:

> 1ª proposta: Prepare arranjos (variáveis indexadas) de, no máximo, 10 posições. Receba o nome, a matrícula e o total de vendas, calcule a respectiva comissão (10% das vendas) de cada vendedor para quantos o usuário desejar. Apresente ao final: a) O nome, a matrícula, o total de vendas e a respectiva comissão de cada vendedor; b) A soma total das vendas; c) O valor da maior comissão e da menor comissão; d) Os dados do(s) vendedor(es) de maior comissão; e) Os dados do(s) vendedor(es) de menor comissão.

### **ALGORITMO QUE EU PROPUS **

```
1º Receber o nome, a matrícula e o total de vendas
```

2º calcule a respectiva comissão (10% das vendas) de cada vendedor para quantos o usuário desejar.

3ºApresente ao final: a) O nome, a matrícula, o total de vendas e a respectiva comissão de cada vendedor

4º  A soma total das vendas

5º O valor da maior comissão e da menor comissão

6º Os dados do(s) vendedor(es) de maior comissão e menor comissão

**DE CODIGÓ EU CONSEGUI FAZER ISSO**

```
Nomes = []
Matriculas = []
totalVendas = []
for i in range(0,3):
addNomes = input(f'Nome do {i+1}º funcionario: ').capitalize()
Nomes.append(addNomes)

addMatriculas = input('Número de matrícula: ')
Matriculas.append(addMatriculas)

addTotalVendas = input('Total de vendas: ')
totalVendas.append(int(addTotalVendas))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizei o seu código e adicionei os itens da questão que estavam faltando e comentei algumas partes do código para uma boa visualização

Segue o código:

```
Nomes = []
Matriculas = []
totalVendas = []
comissoes = []

for i in range(0, 10):
    comissaoVendas = 0.1

    addNomes = input(f'Nome do {i+1}º funcionario: ').capitalize()
    Nomes.append(addNomes)

    addMatriculas = input('Número de matrícula: ')
    Matriculas.append(addMatriculas)

    addTotalVendas = input('Total de vendas: ')
    totalVendas.append(int(addTotalVendas))

    comissoes.append(float(addTotalVendas) * comissaoVendas)


# a) O nome, a matrícula, o total de vendas e a respectiva comissão de cada vendedor;
for i in range(0, 10):
    print("\n--- " + str(i+1) + "º funcionario ---")
    print("Nome: " + Nomes[i])
    print("Matricula: " + Matriculas[i])
    print("Total de vendas: " + str(totalVendas[i]))
    print("Comissão: " + str(comissoes[i]))

# b) A soma total das vendas;
print("\nSoma total das vendas: " + str(sum(totalVendas)))

# c) O valor da maior comissão e da menor comissão;
print("O maior valor da comissão: " + str(max(comissoes)) + "\nO menor valor da comissão: " + str(min(comissoes)))

# d) Os dados do(s) vendedor(es) de maior comissão;
maiorcomissao = float(max(comissoes))
posicaomaior = comissoes.index(maiorcomissao)
print("\nDados do(s) vendedor(es) de maior comissão")
print("Nome: " + Nomes[posicaomaior])
print("Matricula: " + Matriculas[posicaomaior])
print("Total de vendas: " + str(totalVendas[posicaomaior]))
print("Comissão: " + str(comissoes[posicaomaior]))


# e) Os dados do(s) vendedor(es) de menor comissão.
menorcomissao = float(min(comissoes))
posicaomenor = comissoes.index(menorcomissao)
print("\nDados do(s) vendedor(es) de menor comissão")
print("Nome: " + Nomes[posicaomenor])
print("Matricula: " + Matriculas[posicaomenor])
print("Total de vendas: " + str(totalVendas[posicaomenor]))
print("Comissão: " + str(comissoes[posicaomenor]))
```

Comment: Mano pqp ein, muito obg de verdade :0 :) testei o codigo e funcionou perfeitamente, vou estuda-lo

Comment: O objetivo do Stack Overflow [não é fazer exercícios ou o dever de casa dos usuários](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5486#5486). Stack Overflow em Português é um site de perguntas e respostas para programadores profissionais e entusiastas. onde as perguntas devem ser práticas(ou conceituais com aplicação prática), detalhadas e com foco específico. Fora que fazer os exercícios de outra não a ajuda.